# addEventListener для элементов, созданных из функции конструктора

Tags: javascript, конструктор, addeventlistener

Функция-конструктор. Создает кнопку с определенным цветом кнопки. Дожна иметь функцию, при которой, нажимая на определенную кнопку цвет фона страницы становится таким же. Не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы функция работала. Куда и как повесить addEventListener?

```js
let body = document.querySelector("body");

function Button(width, height, color) {
  let button = document.createElement("button");
  body.append(button);
  this.width = width;
  this.heigth = height;
  this.color = color;

  this.create = function () {
    button.style.width = this.width;
    button.style.height = this.width;
    button.textContent = "Click Me!";
    button.style.color = this.color;
  };

  this.changeBackground = function () {
    return function () {
      body.style.backgroundColor = this.color;
    };
  };
}

let button1 = new Button("5rem", "5rem", "green");
button1.create();
button1.addEventListener("click", () => button1.changeBackground());

let button3 = new Button("5rem", "5rem", "red");
button3.create();

let button2 = new Button("5rem", "5rem", "blue");
button2.create();
```

Comment: Зачем так извращение? Почему бы не использовать класс?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const body = document.body;

class Button
{
    constructor(width, height, color)
    {
        this.width  = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.color  = color;
    }

    create()
    {
        this.element = document.createElement("button");

        this.element.width  = this.width;
        this.element.height = this.height;
        this.element.color  = this.color;

        this.element.textContent = 'Click me!';

        body.append(this.element);
    }

    changeBackground()
    {
        body.style.backgroundColor = this.color;
    }
}

let button1 = new Button("5rem", "5rem", "green");
button1.create();
button1.element.addEventListener("click", () => button1.changeBackground());

let button2 = new Button("5rem", "5rem", "red");
button2.create();
button2.element.addEventListener("click", () => button2.changeBackground());

let button3 = new Button("5rem", "5rem", "blue");
button3.create();
button3.element.addEventListener("click", () => button3.changeBackground());
```

или же добавить классу метод addEventListener:

```js
const body = document.body;

class Button
{
    constructor(width, height, color)
    {
        this.width  = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.color  = color;
    }

    create()
    {
        this.element = document.createElement("button");

        this.element.width  = this.width;
        this.element.height = this.height;
        this.element.color  = this.color;

        this.element.textContent = 'Click me!';

        body.append(this.element);
    }

    changeBackground()
    {
        body.style.backgroundColor = this.color;
    }

    addEventListener(type, listener, options)
    {
        this.element.addEventListener(type, listener, options);
    }
}


let button1 = new Button("5rem", "5rem", "green");
button1.create();
button1.addEventListener("click", () => button1.changeBackground());

let button2 = new Button("5rem", "5rem", "red");
button2.create();
button2.addEventListener("click", () => button2.changeBackground());

let button3 = new Button("5rem", "5rem", "blue");
button3.create();
button3.addEventListener("click", () => button3.changeBackground());
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!!! Очень круто! Единственное, нужно this.element.style.width = this.width; и т.д., чтобы стиль кнопок менялся. Спасибо!!!

Comment: @AlenaChuyankova, если ответ решает ваш вопрос - отметьте его галочкой слева от ответа. Если он оказался полезным - стрелочку вверх.

Comment: Решает, я пробовала, но это мой первый вопрос, так что не сильно учитывается. Но если я могу где-то проголосовать за вас в другом месте, дайте знать.